# Google BigQuery equivalent of MySQL multi-table inner join

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know how to write a multi-table join in Google BigQuery similar to this one below for MySQL:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.*, t3.* FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table t3 WHERE t1.field_a=t2.field_a AND t2.field_b=t3.field_b AND t1.field_condition=10
```

Notice that I request the order of the tables in a specific order but using the asterisk functionality.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shorter one, when the columns match names (as in the question):

```
#standardSQL
WITH t_a AS (SELECT 1 id_a, 2 v)
, t_b AS (SELECT 1 id_a, 2 id_c, 3 w)
, t_c AS (SELECT 2 id_c, 5 z)

SELECT *
FROM t_a
JOIN t_b USING(id_a)
JOIN t_c USING(id_c)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t2.*, t1.*, t3.* 
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.field_a=t2.field_a 
JOIN table t3 ON t2.field_b=t3.field_b 
WHERE t1.field_condition=10
```

above assumes there is no ambiguity in fields names

Meantime, below still works in BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.*, t3.* FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table t3 WHERE t1.field_a=t2.field_a AND t2.field_b=t3.field_b AND t1.field_condition=10
```

and is equivalent of

```
#standardSQL
SELECT t2.*, t1.*, t3.* FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN table2 t2
CROSS JOIN table t3 
WHERE t1.field_a=t2.field_a AND t2.field_b=t3.field_b AND t1.field_condition=10
```

Comment: Note these queries will give a "Duplicate column names in the result are not supported" (fixable by removing the .*s)

Comment: Thank you Felipe for double-down on this important aspect. Yes. As I mentioned - above assumes `there is no ambiguity in fields names` . Otherwise, user need either to provide specific list of fields in SELECT statement or use USING(key) syntax - still assuming that no other ambiguous fields rather than keys - so SELECT * can be used. If not  - still explicit list of fields to be used